# PowerShell call SCCM object variable

Tags: powershell, sccm

How does one call SCCM Object variables in PowerShell?

Lets say I have a collection variable on SCCM Objects called "ABC_RegionCode" and it has a different value on every machine in the collection.

How would i call this in Powershell?

`$RegionCode = "ABC_RegionCode"` will just give me the aforementioned string.

Comment: Can you share your skript? You access an property using $Object.ABC_RegionCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily I'd suggest getting this straight from the database, but it's stored encrypted in v_CollectionVariable. If you're on 2012 you can try using Get-CMDeviceCollectionVariable (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821935%28v=sc.20%29.aspx).

So you'd call something like:

```
$RegionCode = (Get-CMDeviceCollectionVariable -CollectionID "SMS00001" -VariableName "ABC_RegionCode").Value
```